# Magento Frontend Exam

Tags: magento2

I have recently gone on to book my Magento 2 frontend exam, I have now seen that there are two different exams, both titled Frontend Certified, does anyone know which is the correct one to take? Have tried to email Magento but no reply as of yet.

The two options I can see are AD0-E710 and AD0-701, both share the title Adobe Certified Expert - Adobe Commerce Front-End Developer.

Answer (score 0):

That one is correct for now AD0-E710